# Image Crop multiple images error

Tags: java, image, jsp, crop

I made the code for image crop in JSP but it is working only for 1 image. For other image it gives the error:

```
java.awt.image.RasterFormatException: (x + width) is outside of Raster
```

Code:

```
try {

    File image = new File("C://Users/Gc/Documents/NetBeansProjects/cropDemo/build/web/images/logo.png");
    BufferedImage image1 = ImageIO.read(image);

    BufferedImage crop = image1.getSubimage(557, 47, 600, 200);
    out.print(crop);
    ImageIO.write(crop, "png", new File("C://Users/Gc/Documents/NetBeansProjects/cropDemo/build/web/images/11.png"));
    String path = image.getName().trim();
    String path1 = "C://Users/Gc/Documents/NetBeansProjects/cropDemo/build/web/images/11.png";
} catch(Exception e) {
    out.print(e);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That RasterFormatException is thrown by getSubImage() when the area specified by [ x,y : x+width, y+height] is not contained within the BufferedImage area.
In your case x+width is outside of the buffered image area.so you need to  give dynamic values for x+width and y+height based on the image area